# auto-close plugin issuse with curly brackets

Tags: vim

I am using vim from terminal as C++ IDE, and I have some issues with the autoclose curly brackets. I am using vim-autoclose plugin.

My problem is that when I am making new function and open curly brackets, the cursor doesn't return inside the function  (inside the curly brackets) but it's returning at the end of the function.. Is there any way to fix that?

Also, when I am creating a new class, is there any way to automatically put a semicolon at the closing curly brackets of that class?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the autoclose plugins that I have seen does not provide the `;` append part on `class and struct`. Hence, I don't use plugins for autoclose and added, in `~/.vimrc`

```
inoremap {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>O
```

After typing `class Test`, typing `{;` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> will render

```
class Test {
    _ //cursor here
};
```

and of course, `indentation` need to be enabled from your end, for instance by `ai` or `cindent`

Here is some more mapping, might not be relevant to `vim-autoclose`, that works fine on plain vim.

```
inoremap " ""<left>
inoremap ' ''<left>
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
inoremap { {}<left>
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
inoremap {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>O
```

The last line gives

```
if (true) {
    _  //cursor
}
```

and whenever, **you don't want the mapping, we need to escape it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>v</kbd> before typing the `mapped char`**

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, i will try this now!

Answer (score 0):

[lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) mapping on `{` will insert the semi-colon when the key is hit while on the same line as `class`, `enum` or `struct`. I haven't taken the time to do something more advanced.

And in all case, the cursor goes back to in between the pair of curly brackets. If you want a newline, you'll have to hit `<CR>`.