# How can I make a key bind that only applies in a certain situation?

Tags: vim

<sup>Note: The bar symbol (`|`) represents the editor caret throughout this question</sup>

---

I've made an UltiSnips snippet like this:

```
snippet "(\w+)" "HTML tag" r
<`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`>$0</`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`>
endsnippet
```

This lets me expand any word into a HTML tag, for example typing "body" and pressing tab expands to `<body>|</body>`.

The caret is placed between the tags. When I now press return, I would like to end up with:

```
<body>
    |
</body>
```

This could be done with a keybind like this:

```
:ino <buffer> <CR> <CR><Esc>O
```

But I don't want to permanently rebind my return key. I only want this specific keybind to be active when my caret is placed between an opening and a closing HTML tag.

How can that be done most simply?

---

Another example is when I have my caret placed between two curly brackets, like so:

```
function() {|}
```

And press enter, I would like the result to be:

```
function() {
    |
}
```

Again this can be done with the above key mapping, but in this case I would only want it to be active when my caret is placed between two curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *map-expression* (see `:h map-expression`) to decide whether what `<CR>` get mapped to when you hit it:

for example the following insert mode map:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-2, 1) =~ '[>{]' ? '<CR><ESC>O' : '<CR>'
```

checks the charachter before cursor and if its `>` or `{` it returns `<CR><ESC>O` in other situations it simply do `<CR>`

In place of conditional ternary expression you could define a full functional function to respond in any situatuion with any pairs; But there is already great plugins that intend to do such tasks gracefully:

[demilitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) and [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) are two famous one.

give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this in [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/), and I remember giving an answer to a very close question here: [How to move opening curly braces to a new line in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708395/how-to-move-opening-curly-braces-to-a-new-line-in-vim)

I define it with:

```
  call lh#brackets#enrich_imap('<cr>',
        \ {'condition': 'getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}"',
        \   'action': 'lh#brackets#_add_newline_between_brackets()'},
        \ 0,
        \ '\<cr\>'
        \ )
```

If you want to distinguish language situations, you'll have to have ftplugins for c (and all other bracket based languages), xml (and other tag based languages) where you have a `inoremap <buffer> <expr>` that tests the context (see the test above) to return either `"<cr>"` or `"<cr><esc>O"`.

```
" to be put in c, js, java, c#... ftplugins
inoremap <buffer> <expr> <cr> getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}" ? '<cr> : '<cr><esc>O'

" to be put in a xml and HTML ftplugin
inoremap <buffer> <expr> <cr> getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="><" ? '<cr> : '<cr><esc>O'
```

You can also define them globally in your vimrc, but then, it will be triggered all the time -- the tests will need to be merged in that case.